# Segfault on calling a function in C

Tags: c, windows, debugging, segmentation-fault, virtual-machine

So I'm building a virtual machine, and trying to make it as cross platform as possible, and suddenly encountering a strange error. There is a `let` instruction for my machine, which allocates memory for a variable in the memory of the machine and assign that variable with a value. In short, the `let` function calls `getAddress` to get the address of the variable. `getAddress` checks if the variable is already defined, and returns the address. If the variable is not defined, `getAddress` calls `memallocate` to allocate memory for the variable, and returns the address. Here is the definition of the functions :

```
static uint16_t memallocate(Machine *m, char *symbol){
    uint16_t allocationAddress = getFirstFree(*m);
    SymbolTable *newSymbol = (SymbolTable *)malloc(sizeof(SymbolTable));
    newSymbol->symbolName = strdup(symbol);
    newSymbol->next = NULL;
    newSymbol->mema = allocationAddress;
    if(m->symbolTable==NULL){
        m->symbolTable = newSymbol;
    }
    else{
        SymbolTable *temp = m->symbolTable;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = newSymbol;
    }
    m->memory[allocationAddress].acquired = 1;
    m->memory[allocationAddress].data.value = 0;
    m->occupiedAddress++;
    return allocationAddress;
}

uint16_t getAddress(Machine *m, char *symbol){
    SymbolTable *table = m->symbolTable;
    while(table!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(symbol, table->symbolName)==0){
            return table->mema;
        }
        table = table->next;
    }
    uint16_t address = memallocate(m, symbol); // Here is the segfault happening
    return address;
}
```

This code compiles and runs pretty well on Linux, but on Windows I'm getting a segfault on the `memallocate` call. Since `memallocate` is directly passed the arguments of `getAddress`, and the arguments both being a pointer, they shouldn't change. But while debugging through CLion, I'm seeing gibberish arguments to the `memallocate` call, which is indicating some kind of stack violation(may be). Again, it is ONLY happening in Windows. Can anybody tell me what is going wrong with my code?
Full code for the project can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/iamsubhranil/VirtualMachine/tree/c).

Comment: 16-bit addresses?

Comment: Yup. The machine also simualtes a RAM-like form of storage. This is the address of the RAM of the machine.

Comment: Have you checked what is on the stack when the call executes?

Comment: Are you talking about `bt` in gdb? Then yes @odin

Comment: Well I meant more like examining the area around the stack pointer to see if you can find the correct arguments anywhere on the stack. That way you can figure out if the problem is that the stack pointer is at the wrong place. Is this being compiled as 64 bit, 32 bit, or 16 bit on windows?

Comment: If there's something wrong with the code presented I'm not seeing it, but nobody knows what your arguments or structs are or what `getFirstFree` does. You should check to make sure `malloc` doesn't return NULL. I suspect the root of the problem originates elsewhere. The fact that its runs fine on that system but breaks on this one is a telltale sign of UB.

Comment: @yano not even the first statement inside `memallocate` is executing. The execution stops right after the `memallocate` call, as shown in the debugger. For the function definition, you can check machine.c in the GitHub link, if that's convenient.

Comment: as soon as you try to step into `memallocate` it crashes?

Comment: That sounds like a corrupted stack pointer, or a stack overflow (full stack).

Comment: 64bit in Windows, with cmake 3.7, using MinGW. Wokring well on Arch Linux and Android with clang 4.0.1. And how to check the SP manually? @odin

Comment: If you are using gdb you can just do x /20x $rsp to examine the area around the stack pointer. If you are compiling in 64 bit though, the arguments should be in %rsi and %rdi anyway not on the stack.

Comment: exactly that is @yano

Comment: alright, `memallocate` has nothing to do with it then (unless you're calling it from somewhere else). Just don't think there's enough code presented here to identify the problem. I'd start with a close examination of `m` and `symbol` and make sure everything there looks good (particularly `symbolTable` and all the `symbolName`s). Sorry I don't have time to go digging through your whole project.. good luck!

Comment: No no not that @yano. Told ya, all the arguments are alright till the `getAddress` call. Just when the `memallocate` is invoked, they are messing up, and the program segfaults. Nothing inside memallocate runs. I'll try to put some more code, atleast the functions `bt` shows. Thanks.

Comment: in `getAddress()` check the  m, symbol before passing them  to `memallocate()`. they must not be `NULL`

Comment: They are not NULL before passing to `memallocate`. Rather, when `memallocate` is called, they are becoming gibberish. @EsmaeelE

Comment: There must be some way for `memallocate()` to return the equivalent of a NULL pointer.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your valuable insights. The problem was with the `Machine` struct, which was too large to keep in stack along with several levels of function calls, as I declared it locally in `main()`. All I did was performing a `malloc` for the structure on the heap instead of local declaration, and it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and run it on linux through valgrind:

```
==13768== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13768==    at 0x109ABE: getAddress (in /home/vonaka/VirtualMachine/machine)
==13768==    by 0x10B714: let (in /home/vonaka/VirtualMachine/machine)
==13768==    by 0x109425: run (in /home/vonaka/VirtualMachine/machine)
==13768==    by 0x109F64: main (in /home/vonaka/VirtualMachine/machine)
==13768==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==13768==    at 0x4C2BE7F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd
==13768==    by 0x109C2F: main (in /home/vonaka/VirtualMachine/machine)
==13768==
```

So (luckily for us) it's not a Windows specific problem. The trick is that on the first call of `getAddress` (when `m->symbolTable` is `NULL`) you call `getFirstFree(*m)` at the beginning of `memallocate`, but look at this function:

```
static uint16_t getFirstFree(Machine m) {
    uint16_t add = 0;
    while(m.memory[add].acquired)
        add++;
    return add;
}
```

`m.memory[i].acquired` for `i` between `0` and `number_of_instructions_in_your_input_file - 1`are all  equal to 1 as you initialize them in `writeInstruction`, but `m.memory[number_of_instructions_in_your_input_file].acquired` is not initialized yet.

So something like this will resolve your problem:

```
void writeInstruction(Machine *m, uint16_t add, Instruction ins) {
    m->memory[add].acquired = 1;
    m->memory[add].type = INSTRUCTION;
    m->memory[add].data.instruction = ins;
    m->occupiedAddress++;
    if(add + 1 < NUM_MEM)
        m->memory[add + 1].acquired = 0;
}
```

Or maybe this is more elegant (if it's works):

```
static uint16_t getFirstFree(Machine m) {
    uint16_t add = 0;
    while (m.memory[add].acquired && add < m.occupiedAddress)
        add++;
    return add;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

First of all about your comment:

> By default, the members of the structure is initialised as 0

**It's just not true!**

Now about why you have segfault without `malloc` and how it's connected with valgrind's warning.

You have variable `m` of type `Machine` and some other variables in the stack, `m` contains `Cell memory[NUM_MEM]` and there is `acquired` in each `Cell` (which are not initialized!). Your input file contains let's say 88 instructions, so first 88 `acquired` will be correctly initialized after 88 calls of `writeInstruction`. Then program start to execute your instructions by calling some functions including `memallocate` and `getFirstFree`. In this loop:

```
while(m.memory[add].acquired)
    add++;
```

for any `add` `m.memory[add].acquired` very likely can be different from 0, so once `add` is equal to `NUM_MEM` you have segfault.

Why it's not happening with `malloc`? Simply because you are lucky (but it's not a *good* luck), your heap is 'cleaner' than stack. Why it's happening only in Windows? Because this time you were not so lucky (I don't have segfault even in Windows).

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for looking so thoroughly through the code. Really appreciate it. Now here's the thing : I told a proper "segfault" as the error, not just the warnings in valgrind. They do not harm the execution of the program and as a matter of fact, I'm well aware of them. Run it in Windows, you'll know what I'm talking about. Secondly, acquired is the flag to denote whether a particular `Cell` is occupied or not, and only when a write in that cell occurs, either data or instruction write, it's value is changed to 1

Comment: By default, the members of the structure is initialised as 0, and that's why I didn't initialise them explicitly. It's a bad hack, and I'll turn around from it soon. Now the actual problem was arising from the fact that the structure `Machine` was (strangely) too large to keep in stack along with 4 or 5 level of function calls, which corrupted the stack. Now when I was calling `memallocate`, for insufficient space, its address was getting messed up, and hence the segfault. To resolve this, all I did was performing a `malloc` for the `Machine` struct in `main()` instead of declaring it locally

Comment: And it solved the problem. Again, this only happened in Windows.

Comment: @Subhranil, I think you don't get it. I edited my answer.

Comment: I absolutely get what you're saying. All I'm saying is I ran the program through the visual debugger in CLion, and saw exactly what was happening : The pointers passed to `memallocate` was getting messed up, but they were perfectly fine till `getAddress`. Since they are the same pointers, they shouldn't change. Moreover, not a single line inside `memallocate` was executing, the segfault was happening on the call itself. You didn't get segfault because you've cloned the repo after I pushed the commits yesterday. I'm pretty sure if you declare `Machine m` locally in `main()`, and pass `&m`

Comment: to the subsequent functions, you'll get it, the segfault will happen again.

Comment: And just the case of `out of bounds access`, valgrind reports those too. `trying to access uninitialized value` is not merely close to that.

Comment: Do try the `Machine m` thing if you got time, I think you'll know. And you can check the commits to find out if you indeed cloned after that specified commit.

Comment: I took your code from d87ee7f to test it on Windows at the moment of writing edit, but it's not important, you have an error in your code and you do not want to fix it, I don't know why, but ok. Of course it's not important if you allocate memory in heap or in stack, so `malloc` can't be a solution. I see you made a proper initialization of `Machine` structure, it's already good, but I suggest you to suppose that I'm not as dumb as you think right now, and imagine what may happen with the program if there are `NUM_MEM` instructions in your input file.

Comment: don't take it otherwise. I know I have such errors and I know how to fix them. I also had this strange Windows only segfault error which I didn't know how to fix, hence I created this thread. If you pick up from d87ee7f, you sure will see the segfault. Here's a couple of things : a) `malloc` is a solution for this case, because it does matter if the stack is overflown so that no new addresses can be pushed in it. b) Inside the initializer, you'll see now I initialized all `NUM_MEM` cells properly now and c) I think you're a very good person who helps people with all his might.

Comment: @Subhranil, sorry, but I don't agree with (a) (maybe there's a reason for using malloc but not as solution of this segfault), thanks a lot for (c) and good luck with your work. In any case I like very much your intention to truly understand your problem by yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152344/discussion-between-subhranil-and-vonaka).